# How can I make an out of range styled component affect the props of another styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

When someone types in an input value that is out of a pre-defined range, I want to show a message. I know how to do this in html/css (example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:out-of-range), but I am struggling to repeat this same functionality using styled components. Here's some sample code:

```
const ErrorLabel = styled.label`
`;

const Input = styled.input`
    // width, height, background-color, border, font-size, margin, padding, color props

    &:out-of-range{
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);

    }
    &:out-of-range + ${ErrorLabel}:after {
        content: 'hi! im after';
      }

`;
```

And then my component is returning code like this (so the input and error tags are not exactly siblings):

```
                <div style = {{other props}}><Input 
                    id = {"value1"}
                    name = {"value1"}
                    min = "5"
                    max = "10" 
                    maxLength="8"
                    onChange = {onChange("result")} 
                    value = {result}/></div>
            <ErrorLabel for="value1">is</ErrorLabel>
```

Comment: Is it required to wrap the input inside a div?

Comment: @lissettdm I can and probably should refactor my code so that I don't need the div, and can make the input and label sibling components. Would that make this question easier to answer?

Comment: Just put <ErrorLabel> inside the div and it'll work.

Comment: @CoPham That worked, thank you!